# Change wordpress website webmaster

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

My brother have a website for his bakery store managed by a company and I decided to take care of it but i know nothing about wordpress yet (I m a python developer)
I have no idea how to preceed. should I call the company and ask them for the code and media file (if there is any?) and I host it myself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WordPress site is composed of two core components. The files (WordPress itself, themes/plugins, uploaded images, etc.) and the MySQL database. If the company is hosting these itself, I would recommend trying to get copies of both of these pieces of data. Then, you'll want to install them on your own WordPress hosting service. You will also need to work with them to get DNS access to point the domain name to the new hosting.

There's no going around getting the current company to provide some data/support. This will likely come at a cost, depending on the existing contract.

Comment: i sow there is a possibility to create a website by drawing it like with wix
If that is the case for my brother's then it will easier right?

Comment: Oh, if you are not set on keeping the existing WordPress site, then, yes. Something like Squarespace or Wix would be easier to roll with.